# Getting my own IPAddress from the viewpoint of my mysql server in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have  server running (on localhost currently) and when I connect to the server (using one of 3 different user accounts) I want to get the IP address from the servers viewpoint.

So lets say I have the server running on the same machine the IP should be 127.0.0.1
If the server is running in a intranet the ip would probably some local ip like 10.10.10.***
And then ofcourse there is a external address if you are connected from another location

Also more than one computer will be able to connect with the same user credentials so I don't know how I could get get the correct ip from mysql.user when there will be multiple ips per username.

Comment: How do you plan to *use* this information? Is there any possibility that the traffic will reach you via NATs? (In which case, the only address you can derive is the IP of the NAT)

Comment: Exposing the database to the internet is not the best idea in my eyes. Perhaps you should change your application in such a way that there is only one component on the server that talks to the db and that manages and serves the clients via a well-defined service.

Comment: The application will have one "server user" which will send some data to the database and "normal users" which will read this data and display it. All of them should have a list users currently connected to the database.